# Updating a YAML File in Windows

Tags: ruby, io, yaml

I'm trying to update a YAML file with the following code:

```
@languages = LanguageList::COMMON_LANGUAGES.sort{ |a, b| a.name <=> b.name }
File.open('c:\\RailsInstaller\\Ruby1.9.3\\lib\\ruby\\gems\\1.9.1\\gems\\language_list-0.1.0\\languages.yml', "w+") do |f|
  f.write(@languages.to_yaml)
end
```

Unfortunately, it's not producing any results. No error messages, either. I followed the instructions [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html) and escaped the \'s. What else might be necessary to open and overwrite a YAML file?

Comment: What contents do you expect to see in the file after running the code and what contents do you actually see?

Comment: What does `@languages.to_yaml` print to the console?

Comment: @DavidGrayson LanguageList::COMMON_LANGUAGES.sort is the languages.yml file I'm trying to open. At the moment, it's unsorted. '@languages' is sorted by name, and I expect the updated YAML file to also be sorted by name. However, it remains unsorted.

Comment: does the directory exist? What does p (f=File.open(path,"w+")) print? Is it actually opening the file?

Comment: @AShelly The directory does exist. I copied it directly from Windows Explorer. As for printing to the console, I get the following in my log: #<File:0x3fc2790>.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It prints the sorted version of languages.yml.

Comment: @timothythehuman: do you have permission to write to the file?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I believe so. I can make/save edits to it in a text editor. So long as I don't require special permissions to save it through Ruby, it should be good.